# Notificación Android

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-notifications

estoy realizando una aplicación, en la que necesito que llegue una notificación, y a través de un PendinIntent, al pulsar en la notificación me lleve a una nueva Activity. Esto ocurriría si estoy fuera de la aplicación, pero si estoy dentro de la aplicación, que me lleve directamente a esa nueva Activity, sin pasar por el pendinIntent. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: Necesitas de cualquier forma un PendingIntent, recuerda agregar el código con el que estés trabajando.

Comment: Agrega el código del `manifest` de tu app, para saber que `launchMode` estas utilizando en tu `Activity`. De igual forma, la forma, el codigo del `PendingIntent` y las banderas que tienes asignadas para el mismo.